# How to declare a variable/list with no int but still be able to divide with it?

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a program that calculates my grade average and I ran into a problem:
I want to calculate the average like this:

```
mathslist = []

def gradesstart():
    mathsgrade = (sum(mathslist))/(len(mathslist))

    print('''Gradeoverview:

Maths: ''' + str(mathsgrade) )
    subject = input("For which subject you want to add a grade? ")

    if subject=="Maths":
         mathslist.append(int(input("Which grade you want to add? ")))

    print("Your grade overview has been updated!")
    gradesstart()

gradesstart()
```

But like this it says that it is not possible because you divide by zero. So I tried to give the list an element like 1 but than it crashes the grade average.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Edit:
I solved my problem from above thanks to one of you but now i want to define two list (mathlistx1 for grades that are evaluated once anf mathlistx2 for grades that are evaluated twice) and i will define mathsgrade like this:

mathsgrade = (((sum(mathslistx1)-1)/(len(mathslistx1)-1))+(((sum(mathslistx2)-1)/(len(mathslistx2)-1))*2))/3

So now I have the same problem as above but with two lists. Just putting it in a if statement : if mathslistx1 and mathslistx2: doesn‘t work

Comment: Your function seems to have an infinite recursion. That is not good, because the call stack is finite. Use a loop instead of recursion

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to compute the grade if there is nothing in the list:

```
if mathslist:  # <- empty lists are falsy
    mathsgrade = sum(mathslist) / len(mathslist)
    print(f'Gradeoverview: Maths: {mathsgrade}')
subject = ...
```

Comment: For this it is working now but how can I do it if I have a calculation a bit more complex like this:
`mathsgrade = (((sum(mathslistx1)-1)/(len(mathslistx1)-1))+(((sum(mathslistx2)-1)/(len(mathslistx2)-1))*2))/3`

Comment: `if mathslistx1 and mathslistx2`, or similar.

Comment: So with this I want to include that the grades are evalueated different so some are evalueated twice and others once. But when I do it like you said and I only add a grade that is evalueated once (mathslistx1) and none that is evaluated twice (mathslistx2) the divided by zero error pops out again.

Comment: So how can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not quite following what you mean with some grades being evaluated once and others twice, etc. Maybe edit that into your original question?